# jquery $.when.apply().done not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have the following code which is working except for the `$.when.apply($, promises).done()` function (I have console logging showing when things are being processed).

I don't understand why the `.done` is not functioning.

What the code is basically doing is for each select in a filter container populate the select with values form an indexed db which is its own function and returns a promise. I can see everything working but the final `.done` is supposed to display items on the screen when everything has rendered, however the screen elements do not show and the page stays white.

```
grid.genPage = function() {
        console.time('genPage');
        $(grid.settings.filterContainer).hide();
        var gridParent = grid.e.parent('div');
        gridParent.hide();
        var promises = [];
        return $.Deferred(function(){
            var self = this;
            if (!grid.settings.startGenPage.call(this, grid)){
                self.reject();
            }
            grid.dtOptions.oColVis.aiExclude = [0];
            grid.displayFields = [];
            $.when(
                grid.buildFilter(),
                grid.buildViews(),
                grid.generateDataTable(grid.showColumns),
                grid.buildManageButtons()
            ).then(function(){
                console.log('start populating filters');
                $.each(grid.config.configs[grid.settings.defaultView], function(i, v) {
                    var p = $.Deferred(function(){
                        var self = this;
                        var field = Object.keys(v); //get field Name
                        if ($.inArray(i, grid.configIgnorArray) > -1) {
                            console.log('ignore resolve');
                            self.resolve();
                        }
                        var c = v[field];
                        if (c.filters.fieldType === 'select') {
                            var el = $('select[name="' + grid.e.prop('id') + 'Filter_' + field + '"]');
                            var os = c.options.objectStore;
                            var idx = c.options.idx;
                            var s = c.options.lookup;
                            $.when(grid.checkCache(el, c.options.objectStore, c.options.idx, c.options.lookup))
                            .then(function(){
                                console.log('select resolve');
                                self.resolve();
                            });
                        }else {
                            console.log('other resolve');
                            self.resolve();
                        }
                    });
                    promises.push(p);
                });
            });
        }).then(function(){
            $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
                console.log('end populating filters');
                console.log('genpage finish');
                grid.settings.completeGenPage.call(this, grid);
                $(grid.settings.filterContainer).show();
                gridParent.show();
                console.timeEnd('genPage');
                self.resolve();
            });
        }).promise();
    };
```

In the above code the `console.log('end populating filters');` never appear in the console. I am sure it's an issue with something not resolving correctly but I cannot see where.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just wondering, same result using `always(...)`? Are you sure you deffered object is resolved??? Quiclkly checking your 'long long code', you never resolve the first deferred object

Comment: `Quiclkly checking your 'long long code', you never resolve the first deferred object` (which you turn as promise btw)

Comment: So just to be sure, set a `console.log()` inside `then()` before it: `console.log('deferred resolved'); $.when.apply($, promises).then(...);`. So is your issue still with `$.when()`???

Comment: @A.Wolff yousir are a star - it was the missing ```self.resolve()``` for the first ```$.Deffered()``` that was holding everything up. if you add that as an answer i'll mark it correct.

Comment: Please mark @A.Wolff answer as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to resolve the first `deferred` object in order to fire the `then()` success callback:

```
self.resolve();
```